# google-gin a provider needs a dependency. NullPointerException BindingsProcessor.java:498

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

In my GWT application i'm trying to setup a DI mechanism wihich would allow me to have all the commonly necessary stuff at hand everywhere. I'm using google-gin which is an adaptation of guice for GWT. I have an injector interface defined as this:

```
@GinModules(InjectionClientModule.class)
public interface MyInjector extends Ginjector {
    public PlaceController getPlaceController();
    public Header getHeader();
    public Footer getFooter();
    public ContentPanel getContent();
    public EventBus getEventBus();
    public PlaceHistoryHandler getPlaceHistoryHandler();
}
```

My injection module is this:

```
public class InjectionClientModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    public InjectionClientModule() {
        super();
    }

    protected void configure() {
        bind(Header.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Footer.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ContentPanel.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PlaceController.class).toProvider(PlaceControllerProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
        bind(PlaceHistoryHandler.class).toProvider(PlaceHistoryHandlerProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

When calling `MyInjector injector = GWT.create(MyInjector.class);` i'm gettign the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createImplicitBinding(BindingsProcessor.java:498)
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createImplicitBindingForUnresolved(BindingsProcessor.java:290)
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createImplicitBindingsForUnresolved(BindingsProcessor.java:278)
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.process(BindingsProcessor.java:240)
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGeneratorImpl.generate(GinjectorGeneratorImpl.java:76)
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator.generate(GinjectorGenerator.java:47)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
```

The problem is that the PlaceController class actually depends on one of the other dependencies. I've implemented it's provider like this:

```
public class PlaceControllerProvider implements Provider<PlaceController> { 
    private final PlaceController placeController;

    @Inject
    public PlaceControllerProvider(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.placeController = new PlaceController(eventBus);
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceController get() {
        return placeController;
    }
}
```

what should i change for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but having the same problem I kept falling here. I finally found the way to know which class is messing during ginjection.

When I launch my app in development mode and put stack to Trace, I noticed there is a step called : "Validating newly compiled units".
Under this, I had an error but I didn't notice it since I had to expand 2 nodes which weren't even in red color.

The error was `"No source code available for type com.xxx.xxxx ..."`, which was due to a bad import on client side which couldn't be converted to Javascript.

Hope this may help other here !

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not actually seeing how the errors you're getting are related to the PlaceController being injected, I do see that the provider is returning a singleton PlaceController even if the provider were not bound as an eager singleton or in a different scope. The correct way to write that provider would be:

```
public class PlaceControllerProvider implements Provider<PlaceController> { 
    private final EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public PlaceControllerProvider(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceController get() {
        return new PlaceController(eventBus);
    }
}
```

Let guice handle the scoping i.e. "Letting guice work for you".

Other than that, I almost bet that your problem is due to the use of `asEagerSingleton`. I recommend you try this with just `in(Singleton.class)` and I further posit that you didn't really need the singleton to be eager. It seems [others had problems](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=48) with the behavior too, there's some indication that it has to do with overusing `asEagerSingleton` or misunderstanding the `@Singleton` annotation in a few cases.

Answer (score 1):

I also got a lot of NullPointerException warnings using GIN 1.x with no real explanation of what happened. When I upgraded to gin 2.0 I was told with high accuracy what the error was. You might be helped by upgrading to the 2.0 version that was released a year after you asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem problem, same trace, and the error was that I used "server" classes in my "client" classes, so GIN can't find these classes.

I mean by "server" and "client" the packages in my project.

Hope this could help